# The asset "application.js" is not present in the asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I'm new in **Ruby** and in **ROR** framework. I try to create web app with JQuery. My steps are:

1. Added gem 'jquery-rails' and executed **bundle install** command from command line
2. String **`//= require jquery2`** added into **application.js** file
3. Now I try include file into page. And I added in  section string **`<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`** into **application.html.erb** file

when I try to see page in browser I see error with message:

```
Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotFound in LandingPage#index
The asset "application.js" is not present in the asset pipeline.
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

What I doing wrong? I googled about this error, but I didn't found anything good explained.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

first of all try to restart your server, generally there is no need to include `application.js` file in assets. if it doesn't work then

add below in your **`config/initializer/assets.rb`** file:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(application.js)
```

**Note:** after adding in your assets file, don't forget to restart your server. If you do any changes in Inilalizers, you have to restart the server to see the effects.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for explanation. I deleted <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %> from head section and added Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(application.js) to assets.rb

Now I see that JQuery doesn't loads on the page.

Comment: @Alex : You don't need to delete `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': true %>` from application layout

Comment: But in this case I get the same error:
The asset "application.js" is not present in the asset pipeline.

Comment: have you restart the server?

Comment: Yep. This is my fault. Server was not been restarted. All works properly after restarting. Problem solved! 
Many thanks for help! :)

Comment: Just as a reminder to anyone it will not work in production unless you do the rails assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production.  I added the Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(applicaion.js) but it still wasn't working (only in production it always worked in Development).

Answer (score 15):

I also ran in this error with Rails 6 (with webpack) using the syntax javascript_include_tag in the application.html.erb file.

With rails 6 and webpack use:

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Comment: I am also using Rails 6, and am still unable to load the javascript. Where is your application.js file located in your directory?

Mine is in: app/javascript/packs/application.js

Comment: My application.js is in the same directory as yours

Comment: You may need to add the application.js copied from a Rails5 app and copied into the location the same as on Rails5 app.

Comment: After two hours only this helped. Maybe this should be marked as solution? Thanks btw

Comment: Sometimes you may need to use both the assets pipeline AND Webpacker. To do it you use javascript_pack_tag first then javascript_include_tag 2nd ("application.js" is what I am referring to).  Unfortunately webpacker doesn't work with coffee script files.  I couldn't get the built in coffee script functionality of webpacker to work so I used both webpacker and the asset pipeline and my older app works now.  I did try the webpacker:install:coffee from "https://l-plan.nl/articles/articles/coffeescript-and-webpacker" but it caused dependencies errors and wouldn't push to Heroku.

Answer (score 11):

If you're running into this problem with a Rails app deployed to Heroku, it's possible that you need to specify the file name.

This is for an app that was previously a Rails 6 app but as I upgraded to Rails 7, the `application.erb` was no longer recognizing my `application.js` file.

I changed this:

```
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload", defer: true %>
```

to this:

```
    <%= javascript_include_tag "/assets/application.js", "data-turbo-track": "reload", defer: true %>
```

and that fixed my Heroku production problem.

Comment: Thanks man! This worked perfectly fine in our Rail 7 project.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted solution above resolves the issue for most but if like me you continued to have problems after following every instruction and every solution. The below might help you.

After going down a rabbit hole of errors, I found the following works.

In my experience, its to do with webpacker and your nvm installation. To try the solution, start by reverting any other actions you did to debug the issue. You need to ensure that you are running the latest webpacker version.

I would then run:

```
    rails webpacker:compile
```

in your terminal.

If it compiles without a node warning then all good. if it gives you a warning about your node version, and or it does not compile, install the latest LTS node version. mine is 16.13.1. for ubuntu. . This is important. The latest version of node is not necessarily the latest lts version. You need to install in your home directory. Run:

```
    nvm install --lts
    nvm use --lts
```

You may want to set this as your default eg. :

```
    nvm alias default 16.13.1
```

Also ensure that your application layout has:

```
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Once that is done run webpacker compile again as above.

If you have any issues after this you can also try adding below in your config / initializer / assets.rb file:

```
    Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(application.js)
```

Comment: What worked in my case was `rake assets:precompile`, since we're not using webpacker.

Comment: Since not using web packer , running the command : rake assets:precompile , also helped me , Thank you  @EricWalker

Comment: do not precompile your assets in development— this is NOT what you should be doing.

Answer (score 1):

This may help some searching for this issue.
Rails: 7.1.1

Built like: `rails new . --javascript=bun --css=tailwind --skip-test --skip-jbuilder --database=postgresql --asset-pipeline=propshaft`

Solution was simple. I just went into `app/assets` and saw there was no `javascript` file and I created it and an empty `application.js`

```
app
  assets
    javascript
      javascript.js
```