# ".js is not present in the asset pipeline"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I know this is a very repeated question but I have done everything by the books, read a bunch of SO posts and none have helped so far.......

assets.rb

```
Rails.application.config.assets.version = '1.0'

Rails.application.config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('node_modules')
```

application.js:

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

production.rb:

```
...
config.assets.js_compressor = Uglifier.new(harmony: true)
config.assets.compile = false
...
```

gems ( i assume can possible affect this):

```
gem 'webpacker'
gem 'react-rails'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.3.1'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
```

application.rb:

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'csv'
require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Shopify14
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.2
    config.serve_static_assets = true
    # config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration can go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded after loading
    # the framework and any gems in your application.
  end
end
```

I tried adding `application.js` to the assets.rb file. (Even though it's already included), but that didn't work.

None of my app/assets/javascript/{} files will work with:

`<%= javascript_include_tag "javascript.js" %>` without the asset pipeline error message in the console.

I am using heroku

Is there something I am missing?

I would rather not directly add these files to the assets.rb file because these are mostly page specific js files i want to use.

Comment: Hi, are you using Rails 6? If not, what version of Rails are you using?

Comment: @mayorsanmayor  'rails', '~> 5.2.2', '>= 5.2.2.1'

Comment: Every time you make changes in the assets.rb file you need to restart your server, the only reason why this will not work is if your js file is not in the assets.rb file and if you added it, you probably forgot to restart your server. Can you confirm this is the case? See this ans - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45237486/the-asset-application-js-is-not-present-in-the-asset-pipeline

Comment: @mayorsanmayor doesn't adding it to my assets folder pre-compile it?